# New to pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

In the following code I would like to understand better what is happening with int *z = malloc(sizeof(int);

To me that creates a pointer to an int. Then *z gets the sum of the value that x points to (2) and the value that y points to (4).

Now *z = 6. Does that mean *z does not point to anything? It just stores an int? I thought *z was a pointer and a pointer is an address? Thank you for any help understanding.

```
int *add(int *x, int *y)
{
    int *z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *z = (*x) + (*y);
    return z;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
    int *ptr = add(&a, &b);
    printf("sum = %i\n", *ptr);
    
}
```

Comment: `*z` _derefences_ the pointer allowing you to read/write to the pointed-to memory location. Don't forget to `free(ptr)` in `main` to release the memory you `malloc`'d. Also, this example is pretty seriously contrived. IRL you'd just do all of this without pointers, stack allocate everything and use the integer return value directly, so maybe it's not a very good motivation for why you'd need pointers.

Comment: Maybe a subtle point, but `z = malloc( sizeof (int))` does not create the pointer.  It allocates ("creates" is not accurate, but I suppose would be used colloquially) the memory and assigns the address of the allocated memory to `z`.  `*z` is not a pointer. `z` is a pointer.  `*z` is the value stored at the address to which `z` points.  A pointer is not an address; it is a variable which holds an address.

Answer (score 1):

> Now *z = 6. Does that mean *z does not point to anything? It just stores an int? I thought *z was a pointer and a pointer is an address? Thank you for any help understanding.

You are correct with `*z = 6` however you are wrong with how this happens.

`z` is a pointer and so it point somewhere into the memory. Earlier in your program, with  `int *z = malloc(sizeof(int));` you have allocated a space the `z` points to.

Then when you did `*z = (*x) + (*y);` you've basically put the result of the addition into that allocated space.

`z` still points to that space (because it is a pointer). `*z` is called dereferencing and has a meaning of reaching directly for the value the pointer points to.

In other words: the `6` is stored in a place the `z` points to and `*z` is a way to grab that value.

Answer (score 0):

`*z = 6` assigns `6` to the location *pointed at* by `ptr`. That's what a pointer does, it points to things, but in order to put a value at where it's pointing as opposed to changing the pointer you need to de-reference with the `*` operator.<sup>1</sup>

Imagine your memory as, conceptually, a number of bytes each of which has a number. A pointer to an `int` represents a particular location in memory which is presumed to hold an `int`, or 4 bytes worth of data.

`*z = 6` means "put an integer value of 6 in the memory location described by `z`", which translates into machine instructions that are largely the same.

`z` absolutely does not "store an int", it stores a location. That location may exist, or may be `NULL`, or may be invalid. There's no guarantees unless you've checked your code carefully to ensure the pointer is valid. That's your responsibility as a programmer.

That's also why pointers can be tricky and frustrating. They introduce *indirection* in your code.

---

<sup>1</sup> In C pointers are also largely interchangeable with arrays so you can do `z[0] = 6`, though as `z` only points to a single int, any index other than 0 is invalid.

Comment: So z stores the address where 6 is located.. then *ptr gets z.. so now *ptr = (address where 6 is located).  What happens to *z? is it no longer pointing to anything?

Comment: If you want to dig deeper then that's great. Try looking at the [assembly language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language) output of that code when compiled. Understanding the CPU's instructions helps a lot with understanding why C is designed the way it is. There's an instruction that says, effectively, "put this value in this memory location" as well as one that says "read from this memory location". `z` itself is not consumed. It's always there. You can do `int a = *z` as easily as you can do `*z += 2`.

Comment: @Dylan No. `*ptr = 6` stores the value 6 in the location referenced by `ptr`.  `ptr` still points at the same location.

Comment: Think of `z` as an "indirect integer", as in you need to dereference it to get one. `z + 6` is doing pointer math. `*z + 6` is doing integer math.

Comment: Remember, conceptually everything in C has a memory address, optimization aside, so `int z` is a memory location as well, you can always do `int* zptr = &z` and then you've got yourself a pointer that can manipulate that value, no `malloc` required.

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry.... so z = (address where 6 is located).. then the address where 6 is located is passed to ptr. So once ptr = address where 6 is located, what happens to z?

Comment: Nothing, it just makes a copy. You can copy pointers and change them around as much as you want, though keep in mind the result of changing them arbitrarily may not necessarily be valid.

Comment: What happens when you do `int x = 5` and then `int y = x`? Same thing. It's just a copy. Pointers aren't special, they just have somewhat magical powers since you can change things *through* them.

Comment: @Dylan It's not "z = (address where 6 is lcoated)". Instead `*z = 6` should be interpreted as "store the value 6 at the location pointed to by z". On the other hand, `z = &x` is "z = the address of x", and `*z = x` is "store the value currently held by x at the address currently held by z"

Answer (score 0):

```
int *z = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

this will envoke a system call for allocating one integer on the heap. z is the address of this integer return from malloc (if malloc fails to allocate z will be null)

z is a pointer to buffer allocated on the heap (if malloc success). in your case this buffer hold one integer so its a pointer to this integer.

see malloc description in man pages. [malloc_man_pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

```
*z = (*x) + (*y);
```

you are right. you are assigning the value that sets in the address x and the value that sets in the address y to the place that z points to.

you dont check the return vale from malloc and this is a very bad thing. always check if malloc successd! see below. maybe you need to check the pointers that you get in x and y ?! (thats up to you, but i recommend to check).

```
int* add(int *x, int *y)
{
    int *z = NULL; 
    
    if(x && y)
    {
        z = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if(z)
        {
            *z = (*x) + (*y);
        }
    }

    return z;
}
```